# Migrating SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, migration, database-migration, database-replication, sqlmigrations

I have a production server with transaction replication in place. I am only migrating the publisher server to a Windows Server 2012 for TLS 1.2 compliance. The SQL Server version is staying the same: 2008 R2. The distribution server and the subscription servers are not being moved. I have one subscription server with 48 separate subscriptions.

I need to find out what is the best way to deal with the replication. The new publication server will not have the same name. So what changes do I need to make on the distribution/subscription servers? Can I generate the script out on the publication server, run it on the new migrated server? I have been discouraged to do the system db restores on the new servers. So I am restoring the publisher databases on the new migrated server. Do I need to do the subscription database from scratch or leave it as is, and once I run the scripts on the publisher server and change some settings on the distribution and subscription server, it will catch on? I'm not sure. Please help if you can. Thanks.